# How to run specific javascript file for the specific website in the chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

This is my service worker file
Even if I am adding the check here all files are running together

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, changeInfo, tab) => {

```
if (changeInfo.status === "complete") 
{
        const url = new URL(tab.url);
        console.log("URL",url);
        
                if (url.hostname === "https://www.linkedin.com/*") {
                
                    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {file: "linkedin.js"});
                }
                else if (url.hostname === "https://www.amazon.com/*") {
                
                    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {file: "amazon.js"});
                }
                else if (url.hostname === "https://www.google.com/*") {
                
                    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {file: "searchResult.js"});
                }
                else
                {
                    console.log("URL NOT FOUND")
                }
}
```

});

Comment: 1) executeScript is in chrome.scripting API and it has different parameters. 2) It's more efficient to declare the [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) in manifest.json instead of using a service worker.